# Integrating WiFi Dongle with Beaglebone Black- Issue

Tags: linux, wifi, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack

I am working on beaglebone black trying to integrate TP link TL-WN721N Wifi dongle which uses atheros driver.
I am using linux 3.2 kernel with ti-sitara rootfs

The problem is when is type the command

```
  wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

it shows                  **Successfully initialised wpa_supplicant**

but it gets stuck there and i have to give ctrl+c to exit from that ,after that i gave

```
 ifup wlan0
```

the response was

```
  Sending discover...
  Sending discover...
  Sending discover...
  No lease, failing
```

after this I repeated the step for wpa_supplicant this time also it gets stuck and when I gave

> ifup wlan0

this time it got the IP and was able to ping..........

This cycles were seemed to repeat when I tried connecting any-other wifi networks  **ie: wpa_supplicant gets stuck two times and on the second attempt of ifup wlan0 only i will be able to get IP**

here is my /etc/wpa_supplicat.conf file

> network={
>
> ```
>     ssid="UTStarcom"
>     #psk="123force"
>     psk=44d83e5c96bd39f47b54625d80b80c79d5b14430d424fdf6636365901b01ab14
> ```
>
> }

and my /etc/network/interfaces

> ```
>  auto lo
>  iface lo inet loopback
>
>  auto eth0
>  iface eth0 inet static
>  address 192.168.2.30
>  netmask 255.255.255.0
>  gateway 192.168.2.1
>
>  allow-hotplug wlan0
>  auto wlan0
>  iface wlan0 inet dhcp
>  wpa-driver wext
>  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
> ```

Can you suggest any solutions for this isuue?

Answer (score 1):

No! Don't Ctrl+C to terminate the wpa_supplicant, it is the daemon there to help you keep connection with the AP and exchange new keys with AP. Try run wpa_supplicant with -B to make it run in background.

You may also consider add control interface and control it over wpa-cli.

Comment: I tried that also but then also and after when I tried "ifup wlan0" I got the result "no lease, failing" .The above combinations I mentioned in the question only gave the wlan connectivity

Answer (score 0):

lsusb to find your usb client. Then, update your system. Use apt-cache search "Your USB Client". If you get a read-out, get back to me. Oh and you need to supply your BBB with the 5V jack instead of the USB to computer.

Seth